# C++: How to compare the content of an array with user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I'm new to programming, so my following question will probably look rather easy to answer for most of you. Here we go:

1. I have an array of strings with predefined content.
2. I ask the user for some input.
3. I'd like to see if the input is identical to one of the elements of the array. 
   3a. If there is a match, I'd like to print out in which "block" of the array it was.
   3b. If there is no match, I'd like to notify the user that there was no match.

So far, I managed to get until point 3a but not further. Please could you give me a suggestion?
Here is my code(let) so far:

```
string fixed_array[4] = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi"};
cout << "Please enter something:\n";
string user_input;
cin >> user_input;
for (int i=0; i!=4; i++) {
    if (user_input == fixed_array[i]) {cout << "Fruit is in " << i << "\n";}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to inform the user if the requested fruit is not in the array, as if I add 'else' after 'if', the program will naturally write out the 'not found' message each time there is a mismatch with an array element.

I was thinking of an exit signal for the loop (bool maybe?): if there is a match within the loop: true, if no match: false. Then use this bool in a simple 'if' statement to print out the 'not found' message.

Is it possible to do it this way, or am I completely off course?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `break;` ?

Comment: Use a flag(bool variable).  If you go through the loop without setting the flag(finding the item) then you will know and you can print the not found message.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre throwing `break`s everywhere is definitely not the way to go

Comment: @deW1: I was just hinting. I avoid answering such basic questions: don't need any downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag, `found` that will set to `true` if the element is found like this:

```
bool found = false;
string fixed_array[4] = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi"};
cout << "Please enter something:\n";
string user_input;
cin >> user_input;
for (int i=0; i!=4; i++) {
    if (user_input == fixed_array[i]) {
        cout << "Fruit is at index " << i << "\n";
        found = true; 
        break; //So the loop ends at the current index. This is not needed though
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    std::cout << "Not Found!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

to search the array.

Then use

> [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

to get the index.

Here is sample code

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string fixed_array[4] = { "apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi" };

    std::cout << "Please enter something: ";
    std::string user_input;
    std::cin >> user_input;

    auto start = std::begin(fixed_array);
    auto end = std::end(fixed_array);

    auto foundLocation = std::find(start, end, user_input);

    bool isFound = foundLocation != end;

    if (isFound) {
        int index = std::distance(fixed_array, foundLocation);
        std::cout << "Found " << user_input << " at index " << index << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an else if statement to your for loop to check if the input is not only different from the output, but if it is the last element of your array of fruits:

```
string fixed_array[4] = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "kiwi"};
cout << "Please enter something:\n";
string user_input;
cin >> user_input;
for (int i=0; i != 4; i++) {
    if (user_input == fixed_array[i]) {
        cout << "Fruit is in " << i << "\n";
        break;
    }
    else if (i == 3) {
        cout << "The fruit is not found.\n";
    }
}
```

This works because if the fruit is found, the else if statement will never run, and if the fruit is found, but it is not the last time the for loop will run, the else if will not execute.  It will only run if the fruit was not found and the for loop is running for the last time, because this means that the fruit is not in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I've put explanatory comments on the needed parts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Define the fixed array size
const int FIXED_ARRAY_SIZE  = 5;
const int NOT_FOUND         = -1;

int main( )
{
    std::string fixed_array[ FIXED_ARRAY_SIZE ] = { "apple"  , 
                                                    "orange" , 
                                                    "banana" , 
                                                    "kiwi"   , 
                                                    "star fruit" };
    std::string user_input                      = "";

    int         fruitIndex                      = NOT_FOUND;


    std::cout << "Please enter a fruit name you would like to search for:" << std::endl;

    // use std::getline instead to assure you can also search for fruits
    // that contain multiple words
    std::getline( std::cin , user_input );

    // you can use the fruit index here with a preset value you can check for 
    // that indicates that it's been found
    for( int i = 0 ; ( i < FIXED_ARRAY_SIZE ) && ( fruitIndex == NOT_FOUND ) ; ++i )
    {
        if( fixed_array[ i ] == user_input )
        {
            fruitIndex = i;
        }
    }

    // check if the fruit has been found and proceed with output
    if( fruitIndex != NOT_FOUND )
    {
        std::cout << "Fruit found on position: " << fruitIndex << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Sorry, the fruit '" << user_input << "' is unknown to me!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::getchar( );

    return 0;
}
```